# Is there any way to find and delete multiple attributes from android layout at once

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have a lot of views in a lot of layout files with some common properties that I need to remove. For the sake of argument let's say I have one layout file with 10 views with one common property which is **android:minWidth** that I need to remove. Is there a more efficient way in the android studio or from the XML file to find and delete them altogether instead of removing them one by one.
If I try the good old ctrl+f to find all occurrences of **android:minWidth** and then try to delete all of them from XML it still wouldn't be efficient because then I'll have to delete the values assigned to the said property one by one because those values are uncommon so cannot be used in find.

Comment: As far as I know this feature is not available yet. You can also file a suggestion ticket in IntelliJ platform if you think this feature will be great.

Comment: `Ctrl + Shift + R` is the only thing you can do with it...

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting you this is not best practice to implement all the parameters in layout.

There is one concept in android **style** for common attributes. We should use style for best practice.

I think you have to remove that parameter using ctrl+f and replace by space one by one.

Comment: I know about **style** and I use it every time on my own projects, but this is someone else's incomplete project that I have to manage and that guy did not do a good job managing or even documenting his code at all. I hate that.

Answer (score 0):

*Click on find and replace button in your android studio and file all **android:minWidth** and replace it with blank or with what you want to replace. Try this it will help you.*

[image]

[image]

[image]